# EKSourceTypeLocal disappear

Tags: ios, ekeventstore

I've a problem with the creation of a custom calendar.
Using the method

```
- (BOOL)saveCalendar:(EKCalendar *)calendar commit:(BOOL)commit error:(NSError *)error
```

I can create the calendar inside the EKSourceTypeLocal.
But when there is an account defined inside the phone (Exchange, Yahoo, Hotmail ...) the EKSourceTypeLocal disappear (whit my custom calendar).

Why?
Should I create my custom calendar in another EKSource?

Comment: I think I answered on your question here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/31142823/2096599][1]