# Can't Create New Calendar EKCalendar no source

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying create a new calendar, not a claendar event, a new calendar.

I found a tutorial online and came up with this code:

```
// Create an Event Store instance
        let eventStore = EKEventStore();

        // Use Event Store to create a new calendar instance
        // Configure its title
        let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)

        // Probably want to prevent someone from saving a calendar
        // if they don't type in a name...
        newCalendar.title = "Some Calendar Name"

        // Access list of available sources from the Event Store
        let sourcesInEventStore = eventStore.sources

        // Filter the available sources and select the "Local" source to assign to the new calendar's
        // source property
        newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
            (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
            source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue
            }.first!

        // Save the calendar using the Event Store instance
        do {
            try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newCalendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "EventTrackerPrimaryCalendar")
            delegate?.calendarDidAdd()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Calendar could not save", message: (error as NSError).localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(OKAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

The problem is the app crashes with an error of: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I did some debugging and found it was this line that is crashing:

```
newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
                (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
                source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue
                }.first!
```

It appears that my EKEventStore sources are empty.

I added this to my plist - Privacy - Calendars Usage Description Value & Privacy - Calendars Usage Description (Privacy - Calendars Usage Description with $(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events but my app still crashes, please help.

UPDATE

My iCloud is completely turned off, I am 100% signed out of iCloud, still no local source, I get the same error.

Comment: Your filter `Array` is empty and your are force wrapping optional property `first` i.e the reason you are getting crash with **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.**

Comment: so take out the first?

Comment: Cant take out the first, i get an error `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((EKSource) throws -> Bool)'`

Comment: What i'm telling you is simply unwrapped the optional using if let like this way. `if let first = sourcesInEventStore.filter({ $0.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue }).first {
            newCalendar.source = first
        }`

Comment: Well I dont get the error anymore, now I have a new problem, I cant save the event now because I have no source :(

Comment: Turns out my iCloud is on, on my device.

Comment: create the else block for the above if and set the `newCalendar.source` with some default value.

Comment: I would need an array with these items: https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/eksource

Comment: When iCloud is turned on, there is no local source, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706969/how-to-create-and-save-ekcalendar-on-ios-6/15980556#15980556

Comment: My iCloud is turned off, I am completely signed out of iCloud and still no local source, same error